# VBA Error: This key is already associated with an element of this collection

Tags: vba, excel

I use the code below to make a collection from a range in excel that is then used to populate a list box on a userform. Code has been working fine for months in two separate macros but suddenly both stopped working and throw error in title.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LR As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim List As New Collection
    Dim Item As Variant
    Set ws = Worksheets("ExpenseCATs")

    With ws
       LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

       For Each cell In .Range("A2:A" & LR)
            With cell
                On Error Resume Next
                List.Add .Text, CStr(.Value)   <---------- Error
                On Error GoTo 0
            End With
        Next cell

        For Each Item In List
                        EXPListBox1.AddItem Item
        Next Item

    End With
```

As all entries are text, I commented out part of the error line as below

```
List.Add .Text ', CStr(.Value)
```

This does not throw an error, but the Listbox does not populate with unique values, instead it lists all items in the cell range.

I've looked at other posts on this error but not able to resolve. Can anyone advise how to fix, also interested in why may have stopped working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In VBA project, Options-->General-->Error Trapping, check `Break On Unhandled Errors`

:)

Comment: Will this be saved to the workbook or is this local to my Excel instance?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this error occurs when adding items to collection and the Key has been used before. .add(key, value) is reverse order to Dictionary object

```
Collection.add(item [,Key])
Dictionary.add(Key, item)
```

for instance:

```
Dim c As New Collection
c.add "Value1", Key:="one"
c.add "Value2", Key:="two"
c.add "Value3", Key:="one" '<----- this is where the error occurs because of duplicate key
```

Of course i can't guess `.value` from your code, but i have seen this error before. Are you sure `.Value` is unique?

Comment: Thanks, but in my case it was the error trapping settings as above