# On Error not working in vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have to catch the error inside the with block. I am reading a file that is , delimeted and then adding the records in a table. If any error occurs move to next line in file

```
    Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, strTextLine

'regex.replaces will replace the commas outside quotes with <???> and then the Split function will split the result based on our replacement
    regex.Pattern = ",(?=([^""]*""[^""]*"")*(?![^""]*""))"
    strArray = Split(regex.Replace(strTextLine, "<???>"), "<???>")
    Set rs = db("ATC").OpenRecordset
    With rs
        .AddNew
        On Error GoTo lpp
        !ATC_ID = Replace(strArray(0), """", "")
        !ATC_NAME = Replace(strArray(1), """", "")
        .update
        .Close
    End With
 lpp:
     'goto next line in the file
     Loop
```

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41553765/4926357) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42457284/4926357)

Comment: @A.S.H already done

Comment: If this chunk is inside a loop, you might be handling wrongly the error, try to show some of the loop's code.

Comment: So, what is it doing now that you don't expect? Please explain more clearly what the issue is.

Comment: its inside a loop let me just post the entire code.

Comment: @A.S.H see the updates

Comment: @RichHolton check updates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an error occurs inside a routine, you cannot just loop and restart with another `On Error`. The rule is:

> You have to call the keyword `Resume` at least once before setting another `On Error`.

Change your loop to something like this:

```
    Do Until EOF(1)
        ' ...
        On Error GoTo ErrHandler
        ' ...

lpp:
    Loop
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    Resume lpp ' <-- make sure Resume is invoked before proceeding with the loop
```

Comment: You should also put an "On Error Goto 0" after the section on code where you expect the error.

Comment: @RichHolton That depends if there are other relevant parts in the routine.

Comment: @A.S.H thanks man works perfectly. Can you please answer this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43439579/how-to-set-column-values-in-a-record-set-in-access-vba